# What is the "JNP" protocol?

Tags: java, jnp

I see URLs like `jnp://localhost:1099/` mentioned when reading about HornetQ. What is the `jnp` protocol? What does it stand for? Where is the specification?

All I could find was [this forum thread, "What is JNP"](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/75457), in which the question does not get answered.

Answer (score 13):

In short, **JNP** is the official JNDI naming implementation of JBoss AS prior to its version < 7.x, based on the JNP project (refer to [the code repo URL](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/projects/naming/trunk/)).

From the [new AS7 documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project):

> Previous versions of JBoss AS (versions < 7.x) used [JNP project](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/projects/naming/)
> as the JNDI
> naming implementation. Developers of client applications of previous
> versions of JBoss AS will be familiar with the `jnp:// PROVIDER_URL URL`
> they used to use in their applications for communicating with the JNDI
> server on the JBoss server.
>
> Starting AS7, the JNP project is not used.
> Neither on the server side nor on the client side. The client side of
> the JNP project has now been replaced by [jboss-remote-naming project](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-remote-naming).
>
> There were various
> reasons why the JNP client was replaced by jboss-remote-naming
> project. One of them was the JNP project did not allow fine grained
> security configurations while communicating with the JNDI server. The
> jboss-remote-naming project is backed by the [jboss-remoting project](https://github.com/jboss-remoting/jboss-remoting)
> which allows much
> more and better control over security.

Its specification is poor, most of the references we find about it are located at JBoss docs prior to the version 7, like in https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r1/html/ch3.chapter.html