# org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory ClassNotFound in Wildfly 10

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I'm trying to migrate an existing JBoss 5 application to work in JBoss 7 EAP / WildFly 10.  Part of the application is trying to access EJBs remotely by doing:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "noone");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "noone");

initContext = new InitialContext(properties);
```

When the app starts, WildFly throws an error message:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory from [Module "deployment.ear-1.0.ear.ear-1.0.servlet-1.0.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

I suspect it's because the `JndiLoginInitialContextFactory` class is no longer in the same package, but I am not sure where to find it.  I've tried running WindUp, but it throws a NullPointerException on startup and doesn't generate a report.

Where do I find this class in Wildfly 10?  I've tried using [Help4j](http://www.help4j.com) to find the class, but it hasn't helped me either.  Is there a library I'm missing for Wildfly 10?

Comment: Is the remote EJB deployed in the same JBoss EAP instance or a different one?

Comment: At the moment, the same one. But need to find a solution for a different instance as well. I'll be leveraging the remote EJBs from a different JB7 container as well as a Tomcat container.

Comment: When I'm connecting to a WildFly 10 instance, I have `properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitalContextFactory");`. That requires the `jboss-client.jar` that is included in your WildFly installation (`/bin/client`).

Comment: Also read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38729176/243373) on SO. I'm reading that the JNP protocol was deprecated in JBoss 7. When I connect to a WildFly 10 instance, I'm using `properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://"+address);`. The naming of your beans is probably different as well, but I'm not familiar with JNP.

Comment: See if you can get some more info here: [Remote EJB invocations via JNDI - EJB client API or remote-naming project](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Remote+EJB+invocations+via+JNDI+-+EJB+client+API+or+remote-naming+project).

Comment: @TT. Thanks - I ran across those links as well, and realize that a lot more changed than just the JndiLoginInitialContextFactory.  It looks like I have some more work to do to use the new protocol(s) instead of JNP.  I read through the wiki docs though, but am not entirely clear how to specify the authentication parameters I want to use in my remote EJB call.  To be more specific, I noticed that there are some auth params in the jboss-ejb-client.properties but those look like just a connection auth.  What about the actual Subject?  How do I pass the subject to the EJB?

Comment: @EricB. The comment section is not really the easiest way to help you out. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "Subject".

Comment: @TT - Sorry - I meant Principal (not Subject)

Comment: @EricB. AFAICT The way you are doing it now. `properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "YourPrincipalHere");` and `properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "YourPrincipalPwdHere");`. At least that's what I'm doing when connecting to WildFly10. This "principal" in my case is a user I added using [add-user.bat](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/add-user+utility).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have calls from EAP 7 to EAP 5? If so you have to package the jbossall-client in your application.

The client code for calling an EJB on EAP 5 will remain the same.

You will need to make sure the needed EAP 5 client jars are packaged with the application.
The missing class in this error is in EAP 5's $JBOSS_HOME/client/jbosssx-as-client.jar.